# Jquery not being read properly until window resize

Tags: jquery, resize, window, margins

so I have a function that takes the size of content (fixed width) as well as the margins and borders, and resizes the container to always keep the content centered, but when the page is loaded, everything always appears in only one column until I resize the window (smaller or  larger both work). Here is a link to the site I am hosting it on as well as the code for the function...any idea why this might be happening and how I could fix this?

http://testingmycode.tumblr.com/

```
function resizeContainer(size, distance) {
var postWidth = size * 2;
var postApart = distance * 3;
return postWidth + postApart + 12;
};
$(document).ready(function(){
var width = Number($('#entry').width());
var margin = Number($('#entry').css('margin-left').replace('px',''));
$('#posts').width(resizeContainer(width,margin));
$('#topbar').width(resizeContainer(width,margin));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try launching your script on window ready instead of on document ready:

```
function resizeContainer(size, distance) {
var postWidth = size * 2;
var postApart = distance * 3;
return postWidth + postApart + 12;
};
$(window).ready(function(){
var width = Number($('#entry').width());
var margin = Number($('#entry').css('margin-left').replace('px',''));
$('#posts').width(resizeContainer(width,margin));
$('#topbar').width(resizeContainer(width,margin));
});
```

Comment: The url you provide works fine in FireFox and Chrome - two columns.
What are you opening it with ?

Comment: in both firefox and chrome? for me it appears one column until I resize the window...why would it be different for me and you?